# On a VM is it possible to get the name of the physical computer(thin client running Windows) used to connect to the VM(also running windows)?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

At work we have several departments that use thin clients that connect to a pool of VM's. The pool is called general and has about 75 VM's in it. One of the departments uses some web based software to do their work. The web based software uses a specific shortcut for each machine. (Example: If you are on a machine named Dog05 then the url for the software would be http:\blahblah.whatever.blahDog05)

The problem is that the web based software uses the printer mappings from the computer name given in the shortcut which would be the VM computer name. The VM's don't have printers mapped because the whole office uses the general pool of VM's. I don't have the authority to change how that is setup and our network admin does not have the time.

What I need is a way to get the computer name of the thin client to the VM and somehow change the shortcut url on the VM.

Thank you very much for any help, and sorry for rambling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using to make the connection to the VM? If you are using RDP there will be an environmental variable within the RDP session named `CLIENTNAME` which contains the name of the RDP client.

Comment: We are using the VMware Horizon View Client. We use that instead of RDP because we have a pool of generic VM's people connect to.

Comment: Blog post on the vmware site if you just look for it. First hit https://www.google.com/search?q=horizon+view+client+name

Comment: I never searched for those exact words. Thank you very much for your help.